# Field theory behind dipole traps / optical tweezers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

I'm trying to re-construct an explain for how an optical tweezer traps a neutral atom with a non-zero dipole.
It began something like this:
"The vacuum is filed with short-lived dipoles form by electron-positron pairs (vacuum fluctuations). If a coherent field is applied to the vacuum, these electron-positron pairs will, during their lifetime, oscillated at the light field frequency. The intensity of the light field determines the amplitude of oscillation. For a Gaussian beam, this will be highest in the beam waist..."

And it then explained how a dipole will be pulled towards the center of the beam. But I forget how this was explain. Does someone know this approach and can help? Also, how can the influence of the detuning (esp. the sign) be explained here.

Thanks!